# (WSL2) git unable to create index.lock AND unable to unlink index.lock

Tags: git, wsl-2

**Problem**

First this occurs whenever I do `git add` or `git commit`.

```
fatal: Unable to create '/mnt/d/xxx/.git/index.lock': File exists.

Another git process seems to be running in this repository, e.g.
an editor opened by 'git commit'. Please make sure all processes
are terminated then try again. If it still fails, a git process
may have crashed in this repository earlier:
remove the file manually to continue.
```

Then, I removed the `index.lock` file, and this error occurs.

```
warning: unable to unlink '/mnt/d/xxx/.git/index.lock': Permission denied
fatal: unable to write new index file
```

After changing the `index.lock` to permission `755` (I also made sure I own this file), the error message went back to the one `fatal: Unable to create '/mnt/d/xxx/.git/index.lock': File exists.`

Basically this makes it a loop of errors and impossible to do any staging and commit. Even restarting the computer after removing the `index.lock` file did not work out.

- However, I found a workaround by switching to `cmd` prompt and do the equivalent `git add`/`git commit` (but I would like to be able to work in WSL2).

**Setup**

- the git project is created with `WSL`, but I did place it in a Windows directory. (it worked fine for a couple of days, and somehow this problem occurred today)
- the ownership of the folders are correctly set to the current WSL user
- there is no other process associated with `git` that is running except for my current session. (I checked in WSL with `ps -fe` and in powershell `get-process`)